# Cross validation in Weka using predefined folds

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

I want to run a 10-fold cross validation train/test experiment using Weka on a dataset that is already divided into 10 folds (i.e. each instance is already allocated to a fold). I know that if you give Weka a complete dataset, it can create the folds for you and run 10-fold CV, but is there a way to tell it which instances should belong to which fold, other than manually splitting the dataset into 10 train/test sets and running each of the 10 experiments independently?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Will you use Java? A simple example of training and evaluating classifiers using the Java interface is given here and excerpted below:
http://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/a-simple-machine-learning-example-in-java/

The first step is creating the splits:

```
// Do 10-split cross validation
Instances[][] split = crossValidationSplit(data, 10);

// Separate split into training and testing arrays
Instances[] trainingSplits = split[0];
Instances[] testingSplits = split[1];
```

And then doing the typical training/evaluation:

```
// For each training-testing split pair, train and test the classifier
for (int i = 0; i < trainingSplits.length; i++) {
    Evaluation validation = classify(models[j], trainingSplits[i], testingSplits[i]);

    predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());
}
```

By contrast, some of my earlier code used the `trainCV`/`testCV` functions to get these instance sets. You could write a new function returning these subsets of the data for your known folds.

Perhaps the source code to Instances.trainCV is a good example of how to build Instance sets:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.7/weka/core/Instances.java

The key lines are calls to `copyInstances`.

```
copyInstances(0, train, first);
copyInstances(first + numInstForFold, train,
      numInstances() - first - numInstForFold);
return train;
```

Perhaps it is also possible to simply create an empty Instances using `new Instances(java.lang.String name, java.util.ArrayList<Attribute> attInfo, int capacity)` and populating using `Instances.get` from the superset of all instances.

Another way would be using a filter, like the following excerpted example when I was training a multiple classifiers with the same splits (in Matlab/java):

```
filterRand = Randomize();
filterRange = RemoveRange();

%if the filterInst parameter is active, take a subsample of training
if doFilterTrain
    rangeStr = sprintf('%g-%g', 1, learnParams.trainSizeMax );
    filterRange.setInstancesIndices( rangeStr );
    filterRange.setInvertSelection( 1 );
end

if doFilterTrain
    filterRand.setInputFormat( instTrain );
    filterRange.setInputFormat( instTrain );

    instTrainSub = Filter.useFilter(instTrain, filterRand);
    instTrainSub = Filter.useFilter(instTrainSub, filterRange);
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I'm using python (yes, I know I should use scikitlearn, I'll get to that eventually). Basically my question was wether there's an easy way to tell Weka where the folds are rather than writing your own trainCV function. If there isn't one, I can just use python to create 10 train/test splits and run Weka on each split separately I guess..

Comment: Specifying Instances for train/test should be sufficient for telling Weka where the folds are, and running training/evaluation yourself. From your perspective, this is more to manage (in fact, it was a pain) but it is the only way I know (not having used Weka for a while).